# R multiply values from different rows

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in R:

```
df <- data.frame(time=c("10:01","10:05","10:11","10:21"),
                 power=c(30,32,35,36))
```

**Problem:** I want to calculate the energy consumption, so I need the sum of the time differences multiplied by the power. But every row has one timestamp, meaning I need to do subtraction between two different rows. And that is the part I cannot figure out. I guess I would need some kind of function but I couldn't find online hints.

Example: It has to subtract row2$time from row1$time, and then multiply it to row1$power.
As said, I do not know how to implement the step in one call, I am confused about the subtraction part since it takes values from different rows.

**Expected output**: E=662

Comment: you have 3 time intervals but 4 consumption values in your example. what do you plan to do with the last value?

Comment: @hyena hey it can be excluded :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tmp = strptime(df$time, format="%H:%M")
df$interval = c(as.numeric(diff(tmp)), NA)
sum(df$interval*df$power, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I got 662 back.